# for which a is this integral bounded

Tags: integration

I am trying to prove that for a > -1 the following integral :

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^a*\lambda * \exp(-\lambda x)dx < \infty$$
> with $\lambda$ > 0

Is there a criteria that I can use to do so ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check boundedness at both ends of the interval.

**Hint** for boundedness around $0$:

What should be enough is to know that $x^ae^{-\lambda x}<x^a$.

---

**Hint** for boundedness at $\infty$:

$$x^ae^{-\lambda x} = \left(x^a\cdot e^{-\frac\lambda2x}\right)\cdot e^{-\frac\lambda2x}$$
and the function in parentheses is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral:
$$
I = I_1+I_2 = \int_0^1 x^a \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx + \int_1^{+\infty}x^a \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx
$$

The first integral behaves as $\int_0^1 x^a dx$, which is convergent when $a>-1$ and the second integral behaves like $\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda x}dx$, which is convergent. In both cases you can get to this result using comparison criteria for improper integrals.